# How to kill thread from inside another thread?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have two functions that are threads (using threading). I would like to kill the first thread by the second thread, once a requirement is satisfied, and allow the second thread to continue running. In code, this is what it looks like:

```
import threading
import time


def functA():
    print("functA started")
    while(1):
        time.sleep(100)

def functB(thread1):
    print("functB started")
    thread1.start()
    x=0
    while(x<3):
        x=x+1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(x)
    print(threading.enumerate())
    thread1.exit() #<---- kill thread1 while thread2 continues....
    while(1):
        #continue doing something....
        pass

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=functA)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=functB,args=(thread1,))
thread2.start()
```

How can I kill thread1 from inside of thread2 and continue to keep thread2 running?

Comment: Killing a thread is not a friendly action.  The right thing to do is to have a "terminate" or "suicide" variable, and have the first thread check that variable periodically.

Comment: Could you show me with an example?

Comment: You may be able to find it for yourself by searching for "[\[python\] is:question kill thread](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aquestion+kill+thread)".

Comment: @Tim Roberts. Is there a way to kill a thread? I thougth there isn't.

Comment: You can always fetch the thread ID and use an OS-specific API.  It isn't friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to use a shutdown flag:

```
thread_a_active = True

def functA():
    print("functA started")
    while thread_a_active:
        time.sleep(1)

def functB(thread1):
    print("functB started")
    thread1.start()
    x=0
    while x<3:
        x=x+1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(x)
    print(threading.enumerate())
    thread_a_active = False
    while True:
        #continue doing something....
        pass
```

BTW, `while` and `if` statements in Python do not use outer parentheses.  That's a bad habit carried over by C programmers.

Comment: I usually employ a parameter to avoid globals

Comment: @azelcer -- In that case you have to be careful to use a mutable type.  A boolean won't work.